# DB2: restore an online backup image that has TSM as log archiving method

Tags: sql, database, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to locally restore a DB2 online backup image from a remote server. I can restore it successfully, but when I try to roll the db forward I get this error:

`SQL2071N  An error occurred while accessing the shared library 
"/home/db2inst1/sqllib/adsm/libtsm.a". Reason code: "2".`

I realized, by looking at the db configuration, that `LOGARCHMETH1` is set to `TSM`, meaning TSM was the log archiving method on the original DB2 installation. I set the value to `disk:/path` and ran the roll forward operation again. This is the status:

```
                                 Rollforward Status

 Input database alias                   = devcldx
 Number of members have returned status = 1

 Member ID                              = 0
 Rollforward status                     = DB  pending
 Next log file to be read               = S0000645.LOG
 Log files processed                    =  -
 Last committed transaction             = 2016-08-30-19.48.31.000000 UTC
```

And this is what I get when I try rolling forward to the end of logs:

```
SQL1273N  
An operation reading the logs on database "DEVCLDX" cannot continue 
because of a missing log file "S0000645.LOG" on database partition "0" and log 
stream "0".
```

Obviously that log file doesn't exist on my local machine.

Is there any way I can complete the roll forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to either:

1. Use the `db2adutl` utility to extract the log files from the TSM server on the source machine and then copy them to the target machine.
2. Install the TSM client on the machine and configure it to act as the primary server so it can retrieve the log files.  (This is somewhat complicated).

Either of these options would allow you to restore to any point in time.

If neither of these is an option, and if restoring the database only to the point in time that the backup completed is acceptable, you have one more option:

3. The database backup image has a copy of the active transaction log file from when the backup was running.  You can extract these to disk.

In your `RESTORE DATABASE` command, you include the `logtarget /path/to/write/files` option: DB2 will extract the included log files from the backup image into the specified directory as it performs the restore.

You can then perform the roll forward to the *end of the backup* using the path:

```
rollforward database X 
    to end of backup and complete
    overflow log path (/path/to/write/files)
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. I took another online backup of the DB and zipped the log files too, so your suggestion #3 solved my problem.